# MySQL select last converstion message between sender and recipients

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I am looking to query a table to get the last conversation between the sender and recipient group by either sender id or recipient id

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` ( 
`message_id` Int( 11 ) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
`author_id` Int( 11 ) NOT NULL,
`recipient_id` Int( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`message` Text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
`date_created` Timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`date_updated` Timestamp NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`recipient_read` Int( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`attachment` VarChar( 64 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( `message_id` ),
CONSTRAINT `message_id` UNIQUE( `message_id` ) )
CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Sample data:

```
+------------+-----------+--------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
| message_id | author_id | recipient_id |          message          |    date_created     |
+------------+-----------+--------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
|          1 |         1 |          101 | Hey buddy, what's up!     | 2019-03-08 11:11:07 |
|          2 |         1 |          101 | Hope all is well? :)      | 2019-03-08 11:11:30 |
|          3 |       101 |            1 | Yes, all good thanks      | 2019-03-08 11:25:04 |
|          4 |       101 |            1 | Super busy right now..    | 2019-03-08 11:25:16 |
|          5 |         1 |          101 | Same old stuff everyday.  | 2019-03-08 11:26:45 |
|          6 |         1 |          101 | Yea I guess so! but lis.. | 2019-03-08 11:27:26 |
|          7 |         1 |          100 | Hey man! hit me up, i've  | 2019-03-08 15:43:27 |
|          8 |         5 |          101 | Hola! come sta            | 2019-03-08 15:48:13 |
|         10 |         1 |           99 | Niky nejez sam            | 2019-03-08 16:06:18 |
|         11 |       101 |            1 | Last message!             | 2019-03-08 17:18:44 |
+------------+-----------+--------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
```

What I am looking to query is the last message for a particular user ID and the result should return the last message either sent or received for that user for all users he/she had a conversation with.

For example the query for user ID 1 should return the following:

```
+------------+-----------+--------------+--------------------------+---------------------+
| message_id | author_id | recipient_id |         message          |    date_created     |
+------------+-----------+--------------+--------------------------+---------------------+
|          7 |         1 |          100 | Hey man! hit me up, i've | 2019-03-08 15:43:27 |
|         10 |         1 |           99 | Niky nejez sam           | 2019-03-08 16:06:18 |
|         11 |       101 |            1 | Last message!            | 2019-03-08 17:18:44 |
+------------+-----------+--------------+--------------------------+---------------------+
```

I've been racking my brain all day trying to figure this out and trying out all sorts of sub queries and group by but without any success.

Can anybody point me in the right direction please.

Comment: See if you can ask the same question without including a single picture.

Comment: Also, what kind of value does recipient_read store?

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for the tip. I'll update the question with proper formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a subquery for coupled autors of convdrsation group by max date

```
SELECT  m.* 
FROM  messages m
INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT IF(author_id <= recipient_id, CONCAT(author_id,'_', recipient_id) ,CONCAT(recipient_id,'_', author_id) ) COUPLE, 
    MAX(date_created) max_date 
    FROM  messages
    GROUP BY COUPLE 
) t ON IF(m.author_id <= m.recipient_id,
         CONCAT(m.author_id,'_', m.recipient_id),
         CONCAT(m.recipient_id,'_', m.author_id) )  = t.COUPLE 
AND t.max_date  = m.date_created
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @scaisEdge, this query return what I was expecting. A few typo in the query though. Comma between COUPLE, MAX and change mauthor_id to m.author_id

Comment: After doing some tests @scaisEdge I noticed that this query works only there are no 2 messages posted at the exact same time. If both author and recipient post a message at the exact same date_time then a duplicate row is returned

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but I guess this is what you need as per your expected result.

```
SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (author_id = 1 OR recipient_id = 1) ORDER BY 
 date_updated DESC) 
ORDER BY message_id ASC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Yes there shouldn't be any limits, all conversations should be selected

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need a `UNION` and and `GROUP BY` on each `SELECT` to get `author_id ,recipient_id` and `data_updated` that you are looking for, and then a `INNER JOIN` between the subquery created and the `messages` table to get the other data:

```
SELECT  message_id
       ,author_id
       ,recipient_id
       ,message
       ,data_created
       ,data_updated
FROM   messages M
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
            author_id
           ,recipient_id
           ,MAX(date_updated) AS data_updated
    FROM    messages
    GROUP BY author_id
            ,recipient_id
    WHERE author_id = 'YOUR_USER_ID'
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT 
            author_id
           ,recipient_id
           ,MAX(date_updated) AS data_updated
    FROM    messages
    GROUP BY author_id
            ,recipient_id
    WHERE recipient_id = 'YOUR_USER_ID') A
ON  M.author_id = A.author_id 
AND M.recipient_id = A.recipient_id
AND M.data_updated = A.data_updated
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT * FROM messages A LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT author_id,recipient_id,MAX(date_created) AS "DC" 
    FROM messages 
    GROUP BY author_id,recipient_id) B 
    ON A.author_id=B.author_id 
    AND A.recipient_id=B.recipient_id 
    AND A.date_created=B.DC 
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT author_id,recipient_id,MAX(date_updated) AS "DU" 
    FROM messages 
    GROUP BY author_id,recipient_id) C 
    ON A.author_id=C.author_id 
    AND A.recipient_id=C.recipient_id 
    AND A.date_updated=C.DU;
```

I purposely type `SELECT * FROM` at the beginning so it will show all columns from table `messages` A and subqueries B & C (basically all of them are the `messages` table). This will allow you to customize which column from the table and/or subqueries. Hope this helps